# Dynamically replace < and > with &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, innertext

I try to make a simple JS function to dynamically replace `<` and `>` inside `pre` elements with `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Why it doesn't work?

```js
let pres = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
for (pre in pres) {
  pre.textContent = pre.textContent.replace('<', '&lt;');
  pre.textContent = pre.textContent.replace('>', '&gt;');
}
```

```html
<pre>
foo <strong>bar</strong>
</pre>
```

Later edit: What I actually want to achieve is that when I open a webpage, `pre` elements should display HTML markup literally, that is:

```
<!-- this is how html works! -->
foo <strong>bar</strong>
```

Comment: When the JavaScript runs, it's already to late - the `<` has been interpreted as HTML. You really need to fix this at the source level, no way around that.

Comment: just `pre.textContent = pre.innerHTML;`

Comment: Btw, `for (pre in pres) {` is wrong, you'll need to use `for … of` or `forEach` or an index loop

Comment: @Bergi, I see you have edited Quentin's answer, thanks. So it seems it is not really too late to workaround this with JavaScript?

Comment: @jsx97 It depends. If the html that you want to display is invalid, contains `</pre>`, contains a `<script>`, contains self-closing tags, or something else, then the damage is already done when the html is parsed, no javascript can help you restore it or undo the potentially malicious side effects. Even `innerHTML` is just a representation of the current DOM state, not the actual source text. So just don't do it. Fix your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<` is a special character in HTML. It represents the start of a tag, not a greater than sign in the text.

Consequently your HTML doesn’t have any `<` in the `textContent`, only in the `innerHTML`:

```js
for (const pre of document.querySelectorAll('pre')) {
  pre.textContent = pre.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<pre>
foo <strong>bar</strong>
</pre>
```

Comment: But he asked about "dynamic replacement of < and > with &lt; and &gt;"?

Comment: @XMehdi01 often it is necessary to establish what the OP is actually trying to achieve which may not always be exactly what was asked. The disconnect is often minor, as in this case where the OP wanted to display the angle brackets literally and thought the way to proceed was to `replace()` them when in fact a different approach was needed. If the disconnect is more severe one enters [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) territory.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach by replacing `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, store it in `result` then wrapped in a `code` tag and assigned it back to the `pre` element.

```js
let preEl = document.querySelector('pre');
let specialChars = {
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;'
}
let result = '<code>';
for (let chr of preEl.innerHTML) {
  if (specialChars[chr]) {
    result += specialChars[chr]
  } else {
    result += chr
  }
}
result += '</code>';
preEl.innerHTML = result
```

```html
<pre>
foo <strong>bar</strong>
</pre>
```